# Component in different Areas, Change default search location

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I had a headach with these component in new feature of ASP.NET Core MVC. My problem is I want to put the component in a specific area but I can't change the default search location of component view.

Here is my Area example. I put the header component of website in a different area:

```
Areas
  Site
    Components
      HeaderViewComponent

  Views
    Shared
      Components
        Header
          Default.cshtml
```

This is the default search location for component. Now in my Header component I send the view with model:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    return View(headerModel);
}
```

I call this component from website Layout which is common to everyone:

```
Views
  Shared
    _Layout

@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(WebUI.Areas.Site.HeaderViewComponent))
```

This doesn't work. And I have the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Header/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Components/Header/Default.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/Header/Default.cshtml
```

This error comes becouse I call the component outside the area. I have another component that I call in the area it works. I tried to define a specific search location

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorOptions(options =>
    //"~/Areas/Site/Views/Shared/Components/Header/Default.cshtml"
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/{3}/Views/Shared/Components/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
});
```

This doesn't work with the components. It seems like component has only their default values. I don't know how to change it.

I found the solution by sending the full name of view, that works:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
     return View("~/Areas/Site/Views/Shared/Components/Header/Default.cshtml", headerModel);
}
```

But I don't like it. If someone know how to override the component default search location that would help :)

Comment: Please don't use the name MVC6, because there is no MVC6. Only ASP.NET MVC 5.x (up to 5.2) and ASP.NET Core MVC 1.x

Comment: Indeed, thank you for correction. And could you have any idea how to fix this problem?